# Solving a Cauchy Euler equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$x^2y'' -xy' +4y=\cos{(\ln{(x)})}$

Characteristic equation :

$r(r-1)-r+4=0 \rightarrow r=1±\sqrt{3}i$

Auxiliary equation

$y=x[A\cos{\sqrt{3}(\ln{x})}+B\sin{\sqrt{3}(\ln{x})}]$

Then what do I do with $\cos{\ln{x}}$

Comment: read something about your equation here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation

Comment: You should say that the method of charactrristic equation you use is not the usual one (I  have understood that thanks to the reference by @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

set $x=e^{t}$ we have 
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dt}\frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{1}{x}\frac{dy}{dt}$$
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{x}\frac{dy}{dt}\right)=-\frac{1}{x^2}\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac{1}{x^2}\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}$$
therefore
$$y_t''-2y_t'+4y=\cos t$$